# why does error handling is not working on syntax error

Tags: exception, error-handling, syntax

try: amount = 10000 if(amount > 2999) print("You are eligible to purchase Dsa Self Paced") except SyntaxError as e: print("error", e)

output: Cell In[169], line 3 if(amount > 2999) ^ SyntaxError: expected ':'

Comment: What language and environment is this?

Comment: See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for how to ask a question and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your code, input, and output as Code Blocks.